# Adding yearly Inflation column according to DateTime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is my DateTime column on a dataframe I want to add two different columns like 'Yearly Inflation Rate of UK' and 'Yearly Inflation Rate of Turkey' according the 'year' on DateTime Column. I need your help how to do it on python

**INPUT:**

```
| DateTime |
|14.08.2014|  
|15.07.2015| 
|16.06.2016|
```

Desired Output:

| DateTime | Inflation of UK | Inflation of Turkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14.08.2014 | 2.36 | 8.85 |
| 15.07.2015 | 0.37 | 7.67 |
| 16.06.2016 | 1.01 | 7.78 |

Comment: Is your question how to find the inflation rates from a random database?

Comment: the question was to get the inflation rate of countries on datetime basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {' DateTime ': {0: '14.08.2014', 1: '15.07.2015', 2: '16.06.2016'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    DateTime
0   14.08.2014
1   15.07.2015
2   16.06.2016
```

**Code**

```
out = df.assign(Inflation_of_UK=[2.36, 0.37, 1.01], Inflation_of_Turkey=[8.85, 7.67, 7.78])
```

`out`

```
    DateTime    Inflation_of_UK Inflation_of_Turkey
0   14.08.2014  2.36            8.85
1   15.07.2015  0.37            7.67
2   16.06.2016  1.01            7.78
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime'). 
df = df.merge(inflation_rates, left_on='Year', right_on='Year', how='left')
df.rename(columns={'UK_Inflation_Rate': 'Inflation of UK', 'Turkey_Inflation_Rate': 'Inflation of Turkey'}, inplace=True)
df.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```